# Construct the covering of $S^{1}\vee S^{1}$ corresponding to the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $a^{2}, b^{2}$ and $(ab)^{4}$.

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-topology

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Construct the covering of $S^{1}\vee S^{1}$ corresponding to the subgroup of 
$\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $a^{2}, b^{2}$ and $(ab)^{4}$.

Note: $\ast$ denotes the free product.

Comment: Hint: do you know about [Cayley graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph)?

Comment: @RobArthan Probably better would be Schreier graphs, since the lifts of the basepoint are cosets of the subgroup.

Comment: @fer2017 Is that supposed to be "subgroup" or "normal subgroup"? The first is infinite-sheeted, and the second is eight-sheeted.

Comment: For the infinite-index subgroup case, I highly recommend this great answer by Lee Mosher: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1489203/265452.  For the normal subgroup (finite-index) case mentioned by Kyle Miller, you can draw this by starting with the number of vertices = index (in this case, 8).  Now you draw four edges coming out of each vertex, corresponding to ($a$, $a^{-1}$, $b$, $b^{-1}$). If each vertex locally looks the same, this is a regular covering space.  For the normal subgroup in the question, this will be an octagon, with alernating sides of $\{a, a^{-1}\}$, $\{b,b^{-1}\}$.